# Two Drop down menu's when "other" is selected in either dropdown open a text box

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I need two drop down menu's that when "other is selected from either menu a text box appears to allow the user to type their answer.

I can create  both drop down menu's and can get one of them to open a text box but I can't seem to get both to complete the same action. I have tried many options and can't get it to work. Can anyone please help.

Thank you

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('association');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('association_detail');
    eSelect.onchange = function() {
        if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 5) {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> 
     <label>Stakeholder association (How you are affiliated with EMWIN):</label>
     <select id = "association" name="association" >
     <option value="na">Select:</option>
     <option value="AR">Academic Research</option>
     <option value="EM">Emergency Management</option>
     <option value="EV">Equipment Vender</option>
     <option value="RB">Re-broadcast</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
     </select>

     </p>
     <div id="association_detail" style="display: none;">
     <input id="namesignup" name="namesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="How you are affiliated with EMWIN" />
     </div>

     <p> 
     <label>Stakeholder association (How you are affiliated with EMWIN):</label>
     <select id = "select_use" name="select_use"  >
     <option value="na">Select:</option>
     <option value="sat">Satellite</option>
     <option value="int">Internet</option>
     <option value="vhf">VHF Radio Rebroadcast</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
     </select>
     </p>
     <div id="Use" style="display: none;">

     <input id="namesignup" name="namesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="How you are affiliated with EMWIN" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues I noticed:

1. Your "other" text boxes both have the same id/name; this does not conform the HTML standard. You need to ensure each element has a unique id.
2. You're only listening to `eSelect` changes; if you want to also toggle the visibility of the `Use` div, you'll need to listen to when the `select-use` changes (ie you need to construct another handler).

Comment: I had but it wasn't working so I didn't add it. I've changed the second one so many time's I'm not sure what would be considered correct.

Comment: You did fabulous I've been stuck on that all morning. Now to only learn how to do database work....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the second select box (id="select_use") and add another onchange handler to it. In this second onchange handler, you will need to select your second textbox (id="use") to show/hide it.

Here is an updated version of your code:

```js
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('association');
    var eSelect2 = document.getElementById('select_use');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('association_detail');
    var optOtherReason2 = document.getElementById('Use');

    eSelect.onchange = function() {
      if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value === 'Other') {
        optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        optOtherReason.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    eSelect2.onchange = function() {
      if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value === 'Other') {
        optOtherReason2.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        optOtherReason2.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ve9fg0tc/2/

Also in your onchange handler, it would be better to show/hide your textbox based on the selected value ('other') rather than the index. This is because you may add/remove more items in your menu in the future so the index will change and the condition won't work anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much I got it! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! It's my first time answering on stackoverflow!